# Replace debug messages by static final strings

Tags: java

It is considered as a good practice to replace hard coded values by static final properties in a java class.

Nevertheless I notice that developers usually keep the logging message hard coded.

Does it makes sense to move logging messages to the static final properties ?

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class));

    public void foo() {
        LOGGER.info("My message");
    }

}
```

**VS**

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    private static final String MY_MESSAGE = "My message";

    public void foo() {
        LOGGER.info(MY_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Comment: The latter can certainly help with internationalisation, and moving towards using string resources for error output.

Comment: No, this is overkill.  In fact, Strings are often self-describing so they donot need a constant.  A constant can be useful if the message is repeated a lot or if the string would be unclear in context (ie, it looks like a magic value) and the constant name would help describe what it represents.

Comment: I'd probably rather use a properties file than clutter with static final variables

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Its always be a best practice to separate Message/Hard code contents. Create other java file (e.g. Message.java) and define all the variables & their values.

You can also used **Externalize string** utility of eclipse.

Comment: The target audience of log messages is the developer.  There is no reason to externalize them for internationalisation.